# ada invalid index constraint

Tags: matrix, slice, ada

I defined a matrix type in ada like this:

`type Matrix_Type is array(Natural range <>, Natural range <>) of Item_Type;`

in order to apply some transformations to an input matrix, I need to define a matrix slice in a function.

I tried that by doing it the following way

```
procedure Do_Stuff(M: Matrix_Type) is
   -- c needs to be half as big as the input matrix M
   C: Matrix_Type(A'Length / 2, A'Length / 2);
begin
   ...
end Do_Stuff;
```

However, compiling fails with the error: `invalid index constraint` which I don't quite understand, since Putting `A'Length` returns a number as `A'Length /2` does. If I declare C using fixed numbers like that

```
 C: Matrix_Type(2,2);
```

everything works fine.

What is the error in that case, the only possible case in which I would understand it kind of would be if I pass some uninitialized Matrix to the function, and even that doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: You say that `C : Matrix (2, 2);` works fine, but it doesn’t here! exactly the same error.

Answer (score 6):

The  [*index constraint*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-6-1.html) for the matrix `C` should be a [*range*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-5.html):

```
procedure Do_Stuff(M: Matrix_Type) is
   -- C needs to be half as big as the input matrix M
   C : Matrix_Type(M'First .. M'Length / 2, M'First .. M'Length / 2);
begin
   …
end Do_Stuff;
```

For non-square matrices, you can use the [*Operations of Array Types*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-6-2.html) to specify a particular index:

```
C : Matrix_Type(M'First(1) .. M'Length(1) / 2, M'First(2) .. M'Length(2) / 2);
```

Comment: Need to be careful about M's lower bound here! What if it’s not 0? or 1?

Comment: Also need to be careful about odd `M'Length`.

Comment: Would not is be better to use `C : Matrix_Type (M'Range(1) / 2 and M'Range(2) / 2)`? In this case no problem with starting index is foreseen.

Comment: Perhaps, with an appropriate [assertion](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Attributes/%27First).